# Using a dataset to create a dictionary of the count of inputs from a specific column with no repeats

Tags: python, pandas, folium

I'm trying to create a dictionary from this csv dataset: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Social-Services/311-Noise-Complaints/p5f6-bkga so that I can create a count of the number of complaints that have been made for each zip code recorded so that I can then map it out into a choropleth map.

This is my code so far:

```
import folium
import pandas as pd

data311 = pd.read_csv('311_Noise_Complaints.csv')

zips = list(data311["Incident Zip"])
zipsND = pd.Series(zips).drop_duplicates().to_list()

newData = {}
occ = 0

for zp in zipsND:
    for data in data311["Incident Zip"]:
        if zp == data:
            newData[zp].append(occ)
    occ += 1

print(newData)
```

But I get this error:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<string>", line 1
DtypeWarning: Columns (15,17,18,20) have mixed types.Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kenia/Desktop/CSCI233/PRAC.py", line 15, in <module>
    newData[zp].append(occ)
KeyError: 11215.0
```

I'm not exactly sure what the error is telling me. Is the issue how I've set up the dictionary and it can't record the first data of the dataset? I also tried moving the indentations in the for loop around (just the `occ += 1` and `print` lines ) but I get the same error

---

[EDIT]

So I ran this code again, but using defaultdict() this time:

```
data311 = pd.read_csv(311_Noise_Complaints.csv')

zips = list(data311["Incident Zip"])
zipsND = pd.Series(zips).drop_duplicates().to_list()

new = defaultdict(list)
count = 0

for (zp, count) in zipsND:
    if zp in zips:
        count += 1
        new[zp].append(count)

print(new)
```

But now I get this error:

```
line 13, in <module>
    for (zp, count) in zipsND:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object
```

---

[EDIT 2]

```
zips = list(data311["Incident Zip"])
zipsND = pd.Series(zips).drop_duplicates().to_list()

new = defaultdict(list)
count = 0

for zp in zipsND:
    if zp in zips:
        new[zp] = [count]
    count += 1
print(new)
```

I get results with this code, but the values are not correct. It just counts each zipcode; so the first zip code has a value of 0, the second 1 and so on. I need each zipcode to have the total number of complaints that were made within that zipcode.

Comment: Use setdefault to add. If it doesnt exist, it will add what you ask it to add. Alternate is to use defaultdict. Its the best way to add if you want to add a list to the dict key

Comment: I edited my code and tried using defaultdict(). Is this what you meant? I'm new to programming/python so I had to do some research on how it works, but I guess I'm still doing something wrong. Do you mind altering my code to show me how I can get it to run?

Comment: `new[zp].append(count)`  change this to `new[zp] = count`

Comment: Do you just need a dictionary of all the items in a dataframe? Why dont you do to_dict instead

Comment: I can work on this in the evening but its much simpler that what you are trying to do. I think you have a dataframe and it has dup zipcodes. You just need a count of the zipcodes and that result to be stored as a dict. Correct?

Comment: I want to make a dictionary that has the total number of 311 complaints that were made for each zip code. And then I want to use that data/dictionary to create a choropleth map.

Comment: The zip code and frequency are sought in this.`df['Incident Zip'].value_counts().to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

Initially, there is nothing in `newData`, so the first time you try to add to `newData[zp]`, there isn't anything to append to.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
data311 = pd.read_csv('311_Noise_Complaints.csv')
f = data311.groupby(['Incident Zip']).agg({'Incident Zip':'count'}).to_dict()
print (f)
```

The output of this will be (i picked the first 160 rows as a sample set):

```
{'Incident Zip': {10001: 1, 10002: 1, 10009: 1, 10010: 1, 10011: 1, 10012: 1, 10019: 3, 10023: 1, 10024: 2, 10025: 2, 10026: 1, 10027: 2, 10031: 2, 10032: 9, 10033: 3, 10035: 1, 10036: 1, 10037: 1, 10040: 5, 10302: 1, 10303: 1, 10306: 2, 10310: 3, 10314: 1, 10451: 4, 10452: 2, 10453: 4, 10454: 3, 10455: 1, 10456: 6, 10457: 3, 10458: 3, 10459: 1, 10460: 6, 10461: 2, 10462: 2, 10466: 2, 10467: 5, 10468: 3, 10469: 1, 10472: 1, 10473: 1, 11101: 1, 11102: 1, 11105: 2, 11106: 2, 11201: 1, 11203: 1, 11204: 1, 11206: 3, 11208: 1, 11210: 1, 11211: 1, 11212: 1, 11213: 2, 11215: 1, 11217: 1, 11218: 1, 11220: 1, 11221: 2, 11225: 1, 11226: 5, 11229: 4, 11233: 3, 11235: 1, 11237: 1, 11238: 2, 11354: 1, 11356: 2, 11365: 2, 11368: 2, 11372: 1, 11373: 1, 11374: 1, 11377: 2, 11378: 1, 11385: 2, 11414: 1, 11416: 1, 11418: 1, 11419: 2, 11420: 1, 11435: 1}}
```

**EDIT 1:**

This is an updated code.

```
import pandas as pd
data311 = pd.read_csv('311_noise_complaints.csv')
zips = list(data311["Incident Zip"])
f = data311[['Unique Key','Incident Zip']].groupby(['Incident Zip']).agg('count').to_dict()
print (f)
```

The output is as shown below.

**I ran it against the full 311 file.**

```
{'Unique Key': {0.0: 1, 83.0: 337, 10000.0: 723, 10001.0: 26972, 10002.0: 56853, 10003.0: 44626, 10004.0: 3578, 10005.0: 6361, 10006.0: 3769, 10007.0: 7187, 10009.0: 55194, 10010.0: 19225, 10011.0: 34350, 10012.0: 26946, 10013.0: 25343, 10014.0: 27155, 10016.0: 36739, 10017.0: 10850, 10018.0: 9491, 10019.0: 33394, 10020.0: 237, 10021.0: 12556, 10022.0: 16395, 10023.0: 24528, 10024.0: 28261, 10025.0: 50183, 10026.0: 42993, 10027.0: 50355, 10028.0: 19946, 10029.0: 52997, 10030.0: 29588, 10031.0: 76699, 10032.0: 71851, 10033.0: 55417, 10034.0: 66645, 10035.0: 25192, 10036.0: 24200, 10037.0: 13804, 10038.0: 15350, 10039.0: 26660, 10040.0: 66489, 10041.0: 57, 10044.0: 649, 10045.0: 12, 10048.0: 33, 10065.0: 11494, 10069.0: 847, 10075.0: 9035, 10103.0: 10, 10105.0: 37, 10106.0: 49, 10107.0: 20, 10110.0: 4, 10111.0: 17, 10112.0: 37, 10115.0: 4, 10118.0: 44, 10119.0: 36, 10120.0: 31, 10121.0: 46, 10122.0: 6, 10123.0: 22, 10128.0: 23133, 10129.0: 9, 10152.0: 9, 10153.0: 18, 10154.0: 5, 10155.0: 1, 10158.0: 56, 10162.0: 139, 10165.0: 10, 10167.0: 2, 10168.0: 3, 10169.0: 9, 10170.0: 30, 10171.0: 3, 10172.0: 5, 10173.0: 1, 10174.0: 19, 10176.0: 1, 10177.0: 10, 10178.0: 7, 10271.0: 16, 10275.0: 11, 10278.0: 31, 10279.0: 27, 10280.0: 1679, 10281.0: 346, 10282.0: 676, 10301.0: 16528, 10302.0: 6258, 10303.0: 7632, 10304.0: 16740, 10305.0: 7416, 10306.0: 10304, 10307.0: 2852, 10308.0: 4210, 10309.0: 3885, 10310.0: 11082, 10312.0: 7394, 10314.0: 13363, 10451.0: 31149, 10452.0: 62874, 10453.0: 59162, 10454.0: 20059, 10455.0: 24716, 10456.0: 57692, 10457.0: 58746, 10458.0: 54311, 10459.0: 27283, 10460.0: 38090, 10461.0: 18868, 10462.0: 32137, 10463.0: 41064, 10464.0: 2538, 10465.0: 14298, 10466.0: 95481, 10467.0: 66896, 10468.0: 66413, 10469.0: 21987, 10470.0: 7362, 10471.0: 7065, 10472.0: 43586, 10473.0: 23173, 10474.0: 8207, 10475.0: 3168, 10583.0: 1, 10803.0: 2, 11001.0: 574, 11004.0: 2100, 11005.0: 40, 11040.0: 368, 11096.0: 1, 11101.0: 23341, 11102.0: 18084, 11103.0: 20622, 11104.0: 13449, 11105.0: 14990, 11106.0: 21565, 11109.0: 1441, 11201.0: 38457, 11203.0: 28045, 11204.0: 14174, 11205.0: 32537, 11206.0: 56656, 11207.0: 43003, 11208.0: 41012, 11209.0: 23689, 11210.0: 18774, 11211.0: 56416, 11212.0: 33420, 11213.0: 39695, 11214.0: 16671, 11215.0: 26197, 11216.0: 49235, 11217.0: 32102, 11218.0: 21723, 11219.0: 12134, 11220.0: 29694, 11221.0: 60046, 11222.0: 26228, 11223.0: 17772, 11224.0: 13046, 11225.0: 47689, 11226.0: 77819, 11228.0: 6429, 11229.0: 20586, 11230.0: 24152, 11231.0: 15842, 11232.0: 13360, 11233.0: 34900, 11234.0: 22271, 11235.0: 21506, 11236.0: 25438, 11237.0: 49388, 11238.0: 51740, 11239.0: 1375, 11241.0: 4, 11242.0: 10, 11243.0: 4, 11249.0: 23555, 11251.0: 1, 11354.0: 11975, 11355.0: 14236, 11356.0: 10640, 11357.0: 6729, 11358.0: 7297, 11359.0: 12, 11360.0: 2173, 11361.0: 4664, 11362.0: 1723, 11363.0: 1064, 11364.0: 3842, 11365.0: 10384, 11366.0: 27548, 11367.0: 8992, 11368.0: 36096, 11369.0: 13150, 11370.0: 6422, 11371.0: 4, 11372.0: 28212, 11373.0: 25907, 11374.0: 12069, 11375.0: 18285, 11377.0: 27329, 11378.0: 8568, 11379.0: 6748, 11385.0: 45105, 11411.0: 5367, 11412.0: 8934, 11413.0: 7301, 11414.0: 5785, 11415.0: 9684, 11416.0: 11158, 11417.0: 11546, 11418.0: 14633, 11419.0: 24669, 11420.0: 20867, 11421.0: 18786, 11422.0: 5997, 11423.0: 9406, 11426.0: 2480, 11427.0: 4642, 11428.0: 5620, 11429.0: 5097, 11430.0: 38, 11432.0: 25472, 11433.0: 13105, 11434.0: 14533, 11435.0: 18474, 11436.0: 7503, 11691.0: 16486, 11692.0: 5150, 11693.0: 5436, 11694.0: 6333, 11695.0: 1, 11697.0: 214, 12345.0: 41}}
```

**EDIT 2:**

You can also use the pandas value_counts() option. This is much faster when you dont use the sort option.

```
f = data311['Incident Zip'].value_counts(sort=False).to_dict()
print (f)
```

The output of this will be:

```
{0.0: 1, 10000.0: 723, 10001.0: 26972, 10002.0: 56853, 10003.0: 44626, 10004.0: 3578, 10005.0: 6361, 10006.0: 3769, 10007.0: 7187, 10009.0: 55194, 10010.0: 19225, 10011.0: 34350, 10012.0: 26946, 10013.0: 25343, 10014.0: 27155, 10016.0: 36739, 10017.0: 10850, 10018.0: 9491, 10019.0: 33394, 10020.0: 237, 10021.0: 12556, 10022.0: 16395, 10023.0: 24528, 10024.0: 28261, 10025.0: 50183, 10026.0: 42993, 10027.0: 50355, 10028.0: 19946, 10029.0: 52997, 10030.0: 29588, 10031.0: 76699, 10032.0: 71851, 10033.0: 55417, 10034.0: 66645, 10035.0: 25192, 10036.0: 24200, 10037.0: 13804, 10038.0: 15350, 10039.0: 26660, 10040.0: 66489, 10041.0: 57, 10044.0: 649, 10045.0: 12, 10048.0: 33, 10065.0: 11494, 10069.0: 847, 10075.0: 9035, 10103.0: 10, 10105.0: 37, 10106.0: 49, 10107.0: 20, 10110.0: 4, 10111.0: 17, 10112.0: 37, 10115.0: 4, 10118.0: 44, 10119.0: 36, 10120.0: 31, 10121.0: 46, 10122.0: 6, 10123.0: 22, 10128.0: 23133, 10129.0: 9, 10152.0: 9, 10153.0: 18, 10154.0: 5, 10155.0: 1, 10158.0: 56, 10162.0: 139, 10165.0: 10, 10167.0: 2, 10168.0: 3, 10169.0: 9, 10170.0: 30, 10171.0: 3, 10172.0: 5, 10173.0: 1, 10174.0: 19, 10176.0: 1, 10177.0: 10, 10178.0: 7, 10271.0: 16, 10275.0: 11, 10278.0: 31, 10279.0: 27, 10280.0: 1679, 10281.0: 346, 10282.0: 676, 10301.0: 16528, 10302.0: 6258, 10303.0: 7632, 10304.0: 16740, 10305.0: 7416, 10306.0: 10304, 10307.0: 2852, 10308.0: 4210, 10309.0: 3885, 10310.0: 11082, 10312.0: 7394, 10314.0: 13363, 10451.0: 31149, 10452.0: 62874, 10453.0: 59162, 10454.0: 20059, 10455.0: 24716, 10456.0: 57692, 10457.0: 58746, 10458.0: 54311, 10459.0: 27283, 10460.0: 38090, 10461.0: 18868, 10462.0: 32137, 10463.0: 41064, 10464.0: 2538, 10465.0: 14298, 10466.0: 95481, 10467.0: 66896, 10468.0: 66413, 10469.0: 21987, 10470.0: 7362, 10471.0: 7065, 10472.0: 43586, 10473.0: 23173, 10474.0: 8207, 10475.0: 3168, 10583.0: 1, 10803.0: 2, 11001.0: 574, 11004.0: 2100, 11005.0: 40, 11040.0: 368, 11096.0: 1, 11101.0: 23341, 11102.0: 18084, 11103.0: 20622, 11104.0: 13449, 11105.0: 14990, 11106.0: 21565, 11109.0: 1441, 11201.0: 38457, 11203.0: 28045, 11204.0: 14174, 11205.0: 32537, 11206.0: 56656, 11207.0: 43003, 11208.0: 41012, 11209.0: 23689, 11210.0: 18774, 11211.0: 56416, 11212.0: 33420, 11213.0: 39695, 11214.0: 16671, 11215.0: 26197, 11216.0: 49235, 11217.0: 32102, 11218.0: 21723, 11219.0: 12134, 11220.0: 29694, 11221.0: 60046, 11222.0: 26228, 11223.0: 17772, 11224.0: 13046, 11225.0: 47689, 11226.0: 77819, 11228.0: 6429, 11229.0: 20586, 11230.0: 24152, 11231.0: 15842, 11232.0: 13360, 11233.0: 34900, 11234.0: 22271, 11235.0: 21506, 11236.0: 25438, 11237.0: 49388, 11238.0: 51740, 11239.0: 1375, 11241.0: 4, 11242.0: 10, 11243.0: 4, 11249.0: 23555, 11251.0: 1, 11354.0: 11975, 11355.0: 14236, 11356.0: 10640, 11357.0: 6729, 11358.0: 7297, 11359.0: 12, 11360.0: 2173, 11361.0: 4664, 11362.0: 1723, 11363.0: 1064, 11364.0: 3842, 11365.0: 10384, 11366.0: 27548, 11367.0: 8992, 11368.0: 36096, 11369.0: 13150, 11370.0: 6422, 11371.0: 4, 11372.0: 28212, 11373.0: 25907, 11374.0: 12069, 11375.0: 18285, 11377.0: 27329, 11378.0: 8568, 11379.0: 6748, 11385.0: 45105, 11411.0: 5367, 11412.0: 8934, 11413.0: 7301, 11414.0: 5785, 11415.0: 9684, 11416.0: 11158, 11417.0: 11546, 11418.0: 14633, 11419.0: 24669, 11420.0: 20867, 11421.0: 18786, 11422.0: 5997, 11423.0: 9406, 11426.0: 2480, 11427.0: 4642, 11428.0: 5620, 11429.0: 5097, 11430.0: 38, 11432.0: 25472, 11433.0: 13105, 11434.0: 14533, 11435.0: 18474, 11436.0: 7503, 11691.0: 16486, 11692.0: 5150, 11693.0: 5436, 11694.0: 6333, 11695.0: 1, 11697.0: 214, 12345.0: 41, 83.0: 337}
```

Comment: No, for the zip code 10001, the value should be about 40,300 (I checked on the csv file). I want each key/zipcode to have the value of how many complaints were made within that zip code.

Comment: I got a similar output with the code I added under [EDIT 2] in my original post.